# neo4j java API quick example using REST

Tags: java, api, rest, neo4j

I am trying to get the project from github to work.
It can be found here: https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding

Has anyone put this into a JAR already?  I am to connect to a local neo4j store.  Any other suggestions would be appreciated. I just want to be able to do a quick access of node zero.

Comment: did you get it working using https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding?

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to Axel's answer, here is a good available tutorial where you can find a lot of examples of Neo4J uses (core APIs, indexing, traversals, Cypher and REST interactions): https://github.com/jimwebber/neo4j-tutorial.

Especially, [Koan11](https://github.com/jimwebber/neo4j-tutorial/blob/master/src/koan/java/org/neo4j/tutorial/Koan11.java) class illustrates how to call the built-in REST API, [Koan12](https://github.com/jimwebber/neo4j-tutorial/blob/master/src/koan/java/org/neo4j/tutorial/Koan12.java) shows how to roll your own API via [*unmanaged extensions*](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html).

Answer (score 0):

I recently posted answer to a similar question here.

> [Neo4j, REST API, java - cypher queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21954850/neo4j-rest-api-java-cypher-queries/)

From there you can grab my pom.xml and my java file for your quick example.

Also you might find this tutorial helpful.

> http://thought-bytes.blogspot.com/2013/07/getting-started-with-neo4j-java-rest-heroku.html